# Translation operator in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, hilbert-space

Given the usual translation operator in quantum mechanics:
$$\hat{T}(y)=\exp\left(-\frac{i\hat{p}y}{\hbar}\right)$$
I want to show that $\hat{T}(y)|x\rangle=|x+y\rangle$, as one would hope. I've started off by inserting the identity using the completeness relation $\hat{1}=\int dp|p\rangle\langle p|$:
$$\hat{T}(y)|x\rangle=\int dp \hat{T}(y)|p\rangle \langle p|x\rangle$$
I expand out $\hat{T}(y)$ and substitute the known form of the inner product $\langle p|x\rangle$ (commuting it to the front since it's a scalar):
$$\hat{T}(y)|x\rangle=\int dp\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i\hat{p}y}{\hbar}\right)|p\rangle$$
The $\hat{p}$ operator extracts an eigenvalue from the $|p\rangle$ eigenstate, leaving:
$$\hat{T}(y)|x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int dp \exp\left(-\frac{ip(x+y)}{\hbar}\right)|p\rangle$$
Now I'm stuck. How do I show this is equal to $|x+y\rangle$? I've tried inserting another identity, Fourier transforming and so forth, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It seems you are close. Can you identify $\langle p|x+y\rangle$ in there?

Comment: I can, but how does that help me?

Comment: Oh, of course - I can then reduce it to the identity times $|x+y>$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: small Latex tip: for bra ket notation, instead of "<" and ">", use "\langle" and "\rangle"